# Citrix. Unsigned Active-X doesnt' work in IE 8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, activex, citrix

I have unsigned Active-X and web page that contains that. I managed to open  the web page in IE 8 on dozen of workstations sucessfully after playing with IE 8 security settings. Active-X works fine.

When I moved my solution to Citrix farm everything came broken. Though I installed Active-X on Citrix farm and let client workstation IE settings to run/download/trust every unsigned and signed Active-X - my web page doesn't work correctly. It looks like Active-X was not created or Active-X method calls are disabled

I guess it's something wrong with Citrix politics / security settings. 
What shall I check ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Make a self-signed certificate?

Comment: Yeah, we are going to sign this active-x in a few days & retry. But may be it's possible to make it run without certificates in Citrix?

Comment: You say you 'set client workstation IE settings'.   Are the users connecting to a Citrix desktop?  If so, they will be using the server's IE, not the client's one.  Perhaps edit and define your environment a little better?  As a "Citrix Farm" could be hosting things in a couple/few different ways.  How are the group policies regarding Active-X setup to affect the Citrix server(s)?